# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios

Estuve viendo un tutorial en YouTube para hacer un MERN stack, llegue a la parte que usábamos Axios, pero me salto el error que tengo de titulo. Esta es la parte que hablo

```
const Products = () => {
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const getProducts = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:8085/api");
      setProducts(res.data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("error" + err);
    }
  };
  getProducts();
}, []);

return (
  <Container>
    {products
          .slice(0, 8)
          .map((item) => <Product item={item} key={item.id} />)}
  </Container>
 );
};
```

Y si alguien piensa que tengo que usar Fragment, aca ya lo había escrito

```
  return (
  <Container>
  {products
           .slice(0, 8)
           .map(item => (
             <Fragment key={item.id}>
                 <Product item={item} />
             </Fragment>
             ))}
   </Container>
  );
};
```

Tampoco funciono. (el "Container" que ven ahi, es de la dependencia "styled components"

Comment: Parece pregunta tonta, pero ¿Los `item.id` son únicos? ¿Probaste `key={item.id.toString()}` Por otro lado, aunque [no es recomendado](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#:~:text=Cuando%20no%20tengas%20IDs%20estables%20para%20renderizar%2C%20puedes%20usar%20el%20%C3%ADndice%20del%20%C3%ADtem%20como%20una%20key%20como%20%C3%BAltimo%20recurso%3A) usar el index, dado que no das mucho detalle de como luce la respuesta de tu api, prueba `map((item, index) => <Product item={item} key={index} />)`

Comment: el api son un grupo de diferentes productos, cada uno con su id, nombre, precio, descripción, etc etc

Comment: Deberías revisar bien la data que esta retornando la api, en algún producto si o si debe existir un `id` que se está repitiendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los mas probable es que un `item.id` se repita, parece una respuesta básica pero es equivalente a la pregunta.

Comment: Entonces que sugerís que re-escribiera?